# MySQL get totals from grouped value

Tags: mysql

I have a table that's setup like this:

```
**user_items**
user_item_id
user_id
item_id
```

User's can have the same item_id associated.  If I want to see as a whole, how many items there are assigned to users, this is simply a count.

However, I'd like to the total count factoring in distinct item_id's.  So grouping by the item_id, but as a total.

Any idea how I can do this?

Thank you

Comment: count(distinct...? If it's not that then I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: Actually - yes that's it!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(*) from ...
```

is what you are looking for

EDIT: I'm sorry.. This is indeed wrong. 
There must be an easier solution, but this will do what you want:

select count(*) from (select count(*) from YOURTABLE group by YOURCOL) as WHATEVER;

This counts the rows in the resulting table of the inner query.

Comment: Well, I want to get the `count(*)` when grouping by `item_id`, basically the count of that group by